# Undefined displayed below my table - session storage

Tags: javascript

The code below works but the problem is that undefined is displayed below my table. I tried to remove `sessionStorage.basket === undefined`, but it removes the whole table. Can somebody help me?

```
// Load basket on page
window.onload = loadBasket;

// Displays basket in page.
function loadBasket() {
    // Get basket from local storage or create one if it does not exist
    var basketArray;
    if(sessionStorage.basket === undefined || sessionStorage.basket === "") {
        // Store as an array
        basketArray = [];
    }
    else {
        // Parse the data as an object
        basketArray = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.basket);
    }
    // Build string with basket HTML
    var htmlStr = "<form action='php/checkout.php' method='post'>";
    // Get table body
    var tableBody;
    // Display table headers
    var tableHeader = "<tr><th>Product Image</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Price</th></tr>\n";
    // Store IDs as array
    var prodIDs = [];
    // For loop to display more products on the table
    for(var i=0; i<basketArray.length; ++i) {
        tableBody += "<tr><td class='image_column'>" + "<img class='basket_img' src='" + basketArray[i].image + "'>" + "</td><td>" + basketArray[i].name + "</td><td>£" + basketArray[i].price + "</td></tr>";
        // Push data to insert into the database
        prodIDs.push({
            image: basketArray[i].image, 
            name: basketArray[i].name, 
            price: basketArray[i].price, 
            count: 1
        });
    }
    // Add hidden field to form that contains stringified version of product ids.
    htmlStr += "<input type='hidden' name='prodIDs' value='" + JSON.stringify(prodIDs) + "'>"; 
    // Display the number of items in the basket
    htmlStr += "<p class='basket_items'>Number of items in basket: " + "<span style='color:red'>" + basketArray.length + "</span>" + "</p>"; 
    // Add checkout and empty basket buttons
    htmlStr += "<button class='empty_basket' onclick='emptyBasket()'>Empty Basket</button>";
    htmlStr += "<input class='checkout_button' type='submit' value='Checkout'></form>";
    // Display number of products in basket
    document.getElementById("basketDiv").innerHTML = htmlStr;
    // Display table
    document.getElementById("basket_list").innerHTML = tableHeader + tableBody;
}
```

Comment: It should be `sessionStorage.getItem('basket')` instead of `sessionStorage.basket`

Comment: I did that, but undefined is still displayed

Comment: Did you set value to it?

Comment: No. How do I set the value?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage. Please read this before you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage` until there is no specific reason to use.

**Reason**:
`sessionStorage` is available per window and there is possibility that you have stored value for basket on some other window and trying to get on different window.

> Difference between `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage`:

**localStorage**

Data stored in `localStorage` persists until explicitly deleted. Changes made are saved and available for all current and future visits to the site.

**sessionStorage**

For `sessionStorage`, changes are only available per window (or tab in browsers like Chrome and Firefox). Changes made are saved and available for the current page, as well as future visits to the site on the same window. Once the window is closed, the storage is deleted.

**You problem**:

First make sure you are setting value (**Array of objects**) in `localStorage` properly. Do it like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(basketvalues));
```

Now your condition inside `loadBasket()` function will be like this:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("basket") === undefined || localStorage.getItem("basket") === "") {
        // Store as an array
        basketArray = [];
    }
    else {
        // Parse the data as an object
        basketArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basket"));
    }
```

For more information about localStorage read this link:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: I've changed it to local storage, but I'm still seeing undefined

Comment: How are you storing to local storage? share that code as well

Comment: I changed the sessionSotrage to localStorage, is that correct?

Comment: @User786 first you need to set value to localStorage correctly. How you are setting value to localStorage?

Comment: localStorage.basket

Comment: its wrong. Do like this : `localStorage.setItem("basket", "basketValue");`

Comment: I am updating my answer.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168534/discussion-between-vicjordan-and-user786).